# find min value of a vector and assign the correspoding string

Tags: java

i am having difficulty of finding the right approach of my problem.(noobAlert!)
 I have a FOR loop and inside i calculate a float number and add it in a vector.
 Every iteration of the loop corrisponds to a float number and a name(string).
 After the loop i find the min value of this vector,and my problem is that i cant find a way to "connect" it to the correspoding   string.

I have the impression that it is a stupid question,and that i m searching probably in the wrong places, nevertheless i really need some help here!thnx for your attention..

Every Item  corresponds to a float number which is the result of a ranking algorithm.
 I simply want to get the minValue and its corrisponding Item.:-)

```
for (int j = 0; j < energySource.size(); j++) {
                    Item sourceItem = (Item) energySource.elementAt(j);
                    if (supply.description.isACover(sourceItem.description)) {
                        if (reasoner.checkCompatibility(supply.description, sourceItem.description)) {

                            int RPOT = reasoner.rankPotential(supply.description, sourceItem.description);
                            rSRC = alfaSRC * RPOT;
                        } else {
                            SemanticDescription[] contract = reasoner.contraction(sourceItem.description, supply.description);
                            int RPOT = reasoner.rankPotential(contract[1], sourceItem.description);
                            int RPAR = reasoner.rankPartial(contract[0], sourceItem.description);
                            rSRC = alfaSRC * RPOT + betaSRC * RPAR;
                        }

                        rTOT1 = (alfaTOT * rSRC + betaTOT * rSRC) / depthSrc;
                        totVector.add(rTOT1);



                        if (rTOT1 < minScore) {
                            minScore = rTOT1;
                            bestFunct = supply;
                            bestIndex = j;
                        }

                        System.out.println(supply.name + " + " + sourceItem.name + "    >>>rTOT1 " + rTOT1);

                    } else {
                        candidati.removeElementAt(j);
                        j--;
                    }


                }

                //rTOT1min=>minValue of totVector
                Object rTOT1min = Collections.min(totVector);
                Float bestRank = (float) rTOT1min;  
                System.out.println("  Best Rank : " + bestRank + " Source chosen : " + ______???______);
```

Comment: You need to post some code to illustrate what you're doing.  It's not clear how the numbers and strings are related.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As stated above, a HashMap would be a good option, but if you don't want to change your code too much:

If you are storing all the strings in a list or a vector or some such data structure, then the simple option (without changing too much of your code hopefully) would be to use the indexOf() method to get the index of the min value of the vector and use this to find the string using a  elementAt() method assuming your Strings are also stored in a vector.

Here is a link to the [Vector JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Comment: How are you/where are you storing the source names? You can try and retrieve it using the bestIndex which seems to be the index of the smallest value.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck perhaps with a Hashtable; this will allow you to construct a list where a value is associated uniquely with a key. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: thnx for the quick reply..ill give it a look now

Comment: Hashtable is considered legacy code, you should use a Map instead (for example HashMap) unless thread safety is an issue in which case you could use a ConcurrentMap. Ps: not saying this is the right approach, only commenting on hashtable.